# I need to Open a new tab and Paste a URL to the Url line at the browser, using Python+Selenium. Doesn't work with Keys for some reason

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a Copy Link button at the system I'm testing, and that works. means if I paste it manually (ctrl+v) to the browser's url line , it's ok.
But when I try using Keys nothing happens.

I need to OPEN a new tab, NAVIGATE to it, DELETE the about:blank (from the browser's url line), PASTE the URL, (that's already been copied), and press ENTER

Here is the code:
1)I open a new tab
2)I navigate to the tab

the first 2 actions work well.
the rest don't seem to work for some reason (from this line: action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').perform() )

Code:

```
self.driver.execute_script('''window.open("","");''')
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
profile_window = self.driver.window_handles[1]
self.driver.switch_to.window(profile_window)

action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.DELETE).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').perform()
action.key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','_blank');")
all_handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

**Update 2 :**

You can use `pyperclip` to `paste` as well. see below

```
import pyperclip
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys(pyperclip.paste()).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting guys, I think the problem is that I am not focused on the URL line of the browser, any idea how to switch to that line?

Comment: @Eric : okay, I just checked with `google.com` and `amazon.com` like above in updated 1 code.

Comment: @Eric : try the updated code 2 as well with `pyperclip`

Comment: Both doesn't work. The thing is that I have a link already copied automatically using a button in our system. I need to Paste the link , in the URL line, but I cannot FIRST focus on the URL line...

Comment: You do not need to focus, first one worked for me, second one should work too, but there are two clipboard in system. if you have data copied to universal clipboard then `pyperclip.paste()` should work

Comment: That's the code I use: action = ActionChains(self.driver)
  self.driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','_blank');")
  new_tab = self.driver.window_handles[1]
  self.driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
  self.driver.get(pyperclip.paste())

Comment: Will post the answer

Comment: also, you have the option to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press down before and release CONTROL button before and after sending `a` and sending `v` keys as following

```
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.DELETE).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Your original code simulates pressing CONTROL, then sending `a` key, then pressing DELETE while CONTROL is still pressed, then again press CONTROL button (it was already pressed down) and send `v` button and only now release the CONTROL button and then send ENTER key.
The CONTROL+A or CONTROL+V actions should be: press and hold (key_down) CONTROL, press A (or any other key) release CONTROL button.
If the above still not working you can add short delays between the actions, like this:

```
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)perform()
time.sleep(0.05)
action.send_keys(Keys.DELETE).perform()
time.sleep(0.1)
action.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(0.05)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, if you want to paste a url (that's kept in the clipboard )to a new tab, use this:
It will perform the following:

1. create a new blank tab
2. switch to that that
3. paste the url link that is kept in the clipboard (using pyperclip.paste())

**Code :**

```
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
self.driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','_blank');")
new_tab = self.driver.window_handles[1]
self.driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
self.driver.get(pyperclip.paste())
```